# Customizing biblatex author-year bibligraphy style

Tags: biblatex

I need to follow a journals' bibliography style, similar to author-year.

```
authorlast, authorfirstabbrev. year. jtitle. \emph{journal} vol:pages.

---. year. jtitle. \emph{journal} vol:pages.

authorlast, authorfirstabbrev. year. jtitle. Working Paper.

authorlast, authorfirstabbrev, and authorfirstabbrev authorlast, year, \emph{booktitle}. location.
```

Nicely inconsistent and subtly different from biblatex's author-year.  I understand that various `\Declare*` macros will allow me to do the job, but I need to learn fishing rather than just get someone to give me my fish.  Thus, I would like to go to the source to learn what I can change: where do I find the author-year (bst equivalent) source files to look up what/how I can alter my bibliography.

Also, is there a good document to explains this?  right now, I am navigating by stackexchange examples.